# SwiftLint Rule for Braces on next line but with some exceptions

Tags: swift, regex, swiftlint

I want to modify `.swiftlint.yml` to add some custom rules for enforcing braces on next line. This works for me ...

```
  opening_braces:
    name: "Opening Braces not on Next Line"
    message: "Opening braces should be placed on the next line."
    include: "*.swift"
    regex: '\S[ \t]*\{'
    severity: warning
```

However there are some cases where I want to allow braces on the same line, e.g. something like this:

```
override var cornerRadius: CGFloat
{
    get { return layer.cornerRadius }
    set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
}
```

How do I change my regexp to allow for same line for one-line getters/setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
regex: '^(?![ \t]*[sg]et[ \t]+\{.*\}).*\S[ \t]*\{'
```

Or, its alternative with `\h` matching horizontal whitespace:

```
regex: '^(?!\h*[sg]et\h+\{.*\}).*\S\h*\{'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdkiNC/1/) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/TdkiNC/2)).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\h*[sg]et\h+\{.*\})` - a location in string that should not be immediately followed with

  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `[sg]et` - `set` or `get`
  - `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `\{.*\}` - `{`, any 0+ chars, as many as possible, and `}`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\{` - a `{` char.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This seems to work for most cases. I still get some warnings `Opening Braces not on Next Line Violation: Opening braces should be placed on the next line. (opening_brace)` and they just point to the top line of the source file. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @BadmintonCat No idea, if you can share some sample file text (via pastebin?) I could try to debug the regex, but probably there is no regex issue here, some other rule setting might be at fault.

Comment: You're right! I've copied the affected class into your demo snippet and it looks fine. Must be something else.